# Can two applications share same WCF NetTcpBinding port if they use different end point addresses?

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, servicehost

I have a Client and Server scenario, where a service is installed on the client and another service on the server. I have no issues when these are installed on different machines. However, I would like to also be able to install both the Client service and Server service on the same machine. I could set them up to use different ports, however I would like to accomplish this using a single port.

I have enabled and started the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service Windows service. I start up the Server service first. When I attempt to start the Client service I get the following exception upon executing serviceHost.Open():

`The TransportManager failed to listen on the supplied URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service: the URI is already registered with the service.`

Below is the source code. Both Server and Client use different end point addresses as follows:

**Server Service:**

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerService),
    new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:50000");
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServerService), 
    binding, "ServerService");
serviceHost.Open();
```

**Client Service:**

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClientService),
    new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:50000");
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IClientService),
    binding, "ClientService");
serviceHost.Open();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just resolved it making the base Uri's different during instantiation of the ServiceHost. Revised code follows:

**Server**

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerService),
    new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:50000/Server");
...
```

**Client**

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClientService),
    new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:50000/Client");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also help...working version of TCP port sharing done in Code (vb.net)

http://softwarebykarl.wordpress.com/wcf-shared-tcp-port-in-code/

Comment: This page is no longer available, care to share your solution here?